# Does the Kleene star distribute over each element? (0+1)* = 0* + 1*?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, discrete-mathematics

Does the Kleene star distribute over each element? Is this true: $(0+1)^* = (0^* + 1^*)$?

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried a few examples? Have you tried proving the quality? Is 01 in $0^*+1^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify that $010$ is in $(0+1)^*$ but not in $(0^* + 1^*)$. Therefore, $(0 + 1)^* \neq (0^* + 1^*)$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this makes more sense:

$$ (0+1)^* = (0^*1^*)^* $$

$0^* + 1^*$ would limit the amount of strings covered.